# работа с Git в другой папке

Tags: php, git, bitbucket

Подскажите, пожалуйста.  я нахожусь в папке /test. проект в /test/xx/xx/project. Как сделать remote add repository->commit->push  проекта из папки test?

Comment: `cd xx/xx/project && remote add repository`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd xx/xx/project
git init
git remote add 'ваш проект'
git add *
git commit -m 'message'
git push -u origin master
```

Если вы случайно сделали remote add не в папке с проектом а в начальной папке "test", то вам нужно отвязать его:
1. Смотрим удаленные репо, которые привязанные к папке:

```
git remote -v
```

2. Удаляем случайную привязку

```
git remote rm origin (или другое вашее название)
```